# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists for $0 \le x_{n+1} \le x_n + \frac1{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_1, x_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that

$$ x_{n+1} ≤ x_n + \frac 1{n^2}\text{ for }1≤n. $$

Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists. Help please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence is bounded from above and below, hence both
$$
\ell = \liminf x_n
$$
and
$$
L = \limsup x_n
$$
are finite. Pick $\varepsilon$ and a very large $n$ at which we have both
$$x_n < \ell + \varepsilon$$ and $$\sum_{k \geq n} \frac{1}{k^2} < \varepsilon$$
Then for any $m > n$ using the assumption, we get
$$
x_m < x_n + \sum_{k \geq n} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \ell + 2\varepsilon
$$
Taking $m$ to infinity along a sequence such that $x_m \rightarrow L$ we get $L \leq \ell + 2\varepsilon$. Taking $\varepsilon$ to zero we get $L \leq \ell$. Since trivially $\ell \leq L$ we conclude that $\ell = L$ and therefore the limit exists.

Comment: Why i can take $\varepsilon$ to zero?

Comment: You picked $\varepsilon > 0$ arbitrary, and then proved that $L \leq \ell + 2\varepsilon$. This is an inequality between $L$ and $\ell$ that holds for every $\varepsilon > 0$ so you might as-well take $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ and then get $L \leq \ell$.

Comment: and why the sequence is bounded from  below ?

Comment: because $x_n \geq 0$ by assumptions

Comment: my english is bad but the question is idk why exist L, i can not see the upper bound?

Comment: the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ always exist, but could be infinite. Since $x_n \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$ and $x_n \geq 0$ both the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are also finite in this case.

Comment: oo yea i can see itt

Comment: apriori you know that $0 \leq \ell \leq L \leq \pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 0):

From the given condition and equation, it follows$$0\leq x_{n+1}\leq x_1 +\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2}$$ Taking limits as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get $$0\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{n}\leq x_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=x_1+\zeta(2)=x_1+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: This only shows that *if* the limit exists, then it is bounded between zero and $x_1 + \pi^2/6$

Comment: Yes, thanks @blabler, I should edit my answer.